# What's the meaning of __main__ in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a class that does nothing:

```
class nothing():
    pass
```

when I print the type of my class:

```
p1 = nothing()
print(type(p1))
```

I get:

```
<class '__main__.nothing'>
```

What is the meaning of '__main__'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018653/what-does-main-mean-in-the-output-of-type that is a very common question. Make sure you do some research first before posting questions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a definition of __main__ [https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main\__.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main%5C__.html)

'__main__' is the name of the scope in which top-level code executes. A module’s __name__ is set equal to '__main__' when read from standard input, a script, or from an interactive prompt.

so basically it means you made you defined that class in the file that you ran with python.